# So I'm trying to find a way to replace the items in a string but I seem to be failing

Tags: python, list, indexing, ipython

So I've got this list:
   visual = ['_ ', '_ ', '_ ']
And the user enters a random letter to find the end word (the game is hangman) I have a way of printing it out but it looks like this:

_

o

_

Whereas I want it to look like this:
  _ o _
Or:
 ['_ ', 'o ', '_ ']
I don't mind which one prefer first one.

I have this so far:

```
visuals = ['_ ', '_ ', '_ ']

userInput = input("Enter a letter to guess: ")

index = 0

for ch in hangmanWord:

    index += 1

    if ch == userInput:

        visuals = [w.replace([index], userInput) for w in visuals]

        print(visuals)
```

But the last line doesn't seem to work(I think it's the replacing line)it just comes out with this:

```
   ['_ ', '_ ', '_ ']
```

I want the underscores to be replaced by the users input.

Sorry for its length. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about `join` method of `str`?

Comment: What about `[print(v, end='') for v in visuals]`?

Comment: Aaand you broke the formatting.

Comment: Join just adds the user input at the end not replacing it. It could be just the way I'm doing it if you know a way of doing it with join

Comment: @user2829759 Your method just adds the user input on the end rather than replacing the underscores: unless I messed it up

Comment: Taht's not the full code, right? (if not, write it all)

Comment: what is this code doing `visuals = [w.replace([index], userInput) for w in visuals]`?

Comment: The code is a little messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script solve the problem

```
>>> hangmanWord = "hello"
>>> visuals = ['_'] *len(hangmanWord)
>>> ended = False
>>> while not ended:
...     userInput = raw_input("Enter a letter to guess: ")
...     for idx,ch in enumerate(hangmanWord):
...         if userInput == hangmanWord[idx]:
...             visuals[idx] = userInput
...     print visuals
...     ended = '_' not in visuals
... 
Enter a letter to guess: a
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Enter a letter to guess: h
['h', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Enter a letter to guess: e
['h', 'e', '_', '_', '_']
Enter a letter to guess: l
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '_']
Enter a letter to guess: o
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `index += 1` to after the `if` statement to make the replacements start at 0.

For the replacer, just use `visual[index] = userInput`. It will edit the `visual` based on the index.